# Delphi, How to install a component with the same name in two different package

Tags: delphi, package, components, vcl, bpl

I need to install two different component packages, the first one uses BDE connection and the second one uses FireDAC connection, both of them contain a component called "TKsAnalExpr", which is contained in a unit named "UAnalExpr".

I installed one of the package correctly, but when I try to install the second package, Delphi shows this error message:

> Registration procedure, Kactus@UAnalExpr.Register in package C:\Entorno Delphi XE3\BPL\Kactus.bpl raised exception class EFilerError: Component TKsAnalExpr can't be registered by package kactus.bpl because it has already been registered by package KactusOP.bpl

I changed the name of the units using a namespace, like in for example `PkgeBDE.UAnalExpr` and `PkgeFireD.UAnalExpr` respectively.

But when I try to install the second package again, it shows the same error message above.

I'm using XE3 Upd 1 and FireDAC 8.0.5.

PD: In case someone is wondering, "AnalExpr" stands for "Analizador de Expresiones". Heh.

Comment: Hint: Don't, just don't use "Anal" instead os Analise, Analisis or something like that.

Comment: You redesign your classes so that TKsAnalExpr has a property called Engine, and when you drop it on a form, you connect the Engine property to the TKsBdeEngine or TKsFireDACEngine. Have you not noticed that for example, there is one TDataSource class, and a multitude of TDatasets that can be connected to the TDataSource?  Same idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put, you cannot have two registered components with the same name. There is a single namespace for components within a particular framework (VCL or FMX).

Consider how the streaming framework resolves something like this in a .dfm file

```
object MyComponent1: TMyComponent
```

It knows that it needs to instantiate an instance of `TMyComponent`. So it looks up the class with name `TMyComponent` in that class registry. If it were possible to have two classes with the same name, then that lookup would make no sense.

You have to ensure that the names of registered components are unique.

Comment: thanks for your answer

I understand your point, however in Delphi there are many cases with this configuration, for example: TButton component, which is contained in two Package: dclfmxstd170.bpl and dclstd170.bpl

thanks

Comment: There are special measures taken to segregate components from different frameworks. I don't think that option is available to you. In your .dfm files, when the streaming framework encounters `object Expr1: TKsAnalExpr`, which type would you expect to be instantiated?

Comment: @ErikFerneyCubillosGarcia: a component can exist in multiple packages, but those packages cannot be **loaded** at the same time. `dclstd170.bpl` is for VCL, `dclfmxstd170.bpl` is for FireMonkey. The two frameworks are not designed to be used together, and their respective packages are not loaded in the IDE at the same time.

Comment: @Remy It's a little more complex than that. Both of those packages may be loaded in the IDE at the same time. The namespaces for each framework are segregated.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think that `GroupDescendentsWith` is the key to that segregation mechanism. Maybe!

Comment: How would you handle needing to include multiple third-party packages that include components with the same names?

In my example, I need to include the ActiveX control from Exontrol Ex2Gantt, which wants to register a TItems component but that component is also registered by the Office 2000 object library.

It also contains a TChart component, which is already registered by the TeeChart package.

Surely they should all have separate namespaces, so why is 10.2 complaining when installing the package?